# Document Library: field "Active" got added to Document Content Type

Tags: 2013, content-type, document

In one of our document library field "Active" got added with "Document" content type,  looks like this field got added by activating some feature,  it does not gives us option for removing the field from content type and this is a "Required" field.

I looked at the field details it has following details:-
Field=RoutingEnabled
Fid={3c4e7a5b-b7d5-4779-a14a-490803e63923}

Any idea on what could have added this field with content type,  any way we can remove this from document library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a Content Organizer rule associated with that content type.  Check the Content Organizer site settings to ensure there is no rule associated.

Comment: I don't see content organizer settings on my site settings,  do you know if it is kept in some other place.

Comment: Looks like when you go to the Add new field from site column page,  "Active" field comes up in the top,  however there is no way to delete this field.  We removed this field from library using PowerShell,  but it is still appearing on the documents.